# Rumble support with Gamepads?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, gamepad, gamepad-api

I have read through both the [MDN Gamepad API page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Gamepad_API) and the [W3C Gamepad API page](https://w3c.github.io/gamepad/), and I have found nothing about any rumble features with Gamepads.  I found [one page](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/01/using-the-vibrator-api-part-of-webapi/) that referenced rumble support in FireFox with an android phone, but only had [one comment](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/01/using-the-vibrator-api-part-of-webapi/#comment-7838) that talked about gamepad support.  That comment has 2 links: [a dead blog](http://blog.robothaus.org/2011/12/09/gamepad-vibration-zero-to-hero/), and [a Bugzilla thread](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=680289).  The Bugzilla thread never ended up saying that this feature was added.  I did find [one more page](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/doodles/gamepad/#toc-future) that directly referenced the gamepad rumble control, but it was under the "The Future" section of the post.

Another issue with all these links I gave, is that they are all from between 2010-2013, nothing newer.

Is there a rumble feature for gamepads possible in the current state of web browsers?  And is there a company that has directly said that they are working on it?

Comment: Thank you for your question, Jaketr00. I too have been looking for an answer and the information seems very scarce on the ground. I've set a bounty to call more attention to your post.

Answer (score 6):

There’s the [Vibration API](https://www.w3.org/TR/vibration/) (see also [Editor’s Draft](https://w3c.github.io/vibration/), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Vibration_API)). That [has support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=vibration) in Firefox and Chrome. It is more generally designed for phone vibration than gamepad haptics though, and only supports a single target.

I imagine that what you’re requesting would be better served by being specified as part of a future iteration of the Gamepad API. This is being written on Github, and there’s [an open issue](https://github.com/w3c/gamepad/issues/19) to get it in. Maybe contributing your use cases might help advance its addition?

Comment: So for clarification - these documents you've linked are proposals, and not implemented functionality?

Comment: The Vibration API is a W3 Recommendation: a standard by any other name. That has been implemented in Firefox and Chrome but not in Safari or Edge. In Edge it’s marked as Under Consideration: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/ . Safari doesn’t support it and I can’t find any relevant open issues that says it will. For the Gamepad API vibration support, it’s all still hypothetical. There’s no support, and no proposed method of support.

Comment: It’s also worth mentioning that the nascent WebUSB / WebBluetooth standards might potentially in the future allow for writing a driver in JS that could drive particular pads’ motors directly, but that’s much further in the future than even getting vibration into the Gamepad API specification.

Comment: I've commented on a github issue that was linked in this thread regarding these proposed changes.

https://github.com/html5rocks/www.html5rocks.com/issues/297#issuecomment-222534168

It provides a very in-depth response to the question.

Comment: Also thank you for your answer, it was very helpful! Please take my offered bounty.